# Colored frame around page

Tags: header-footer, color, framed

I am new to Tex. Is there any simple way to create a colored frame around the page? I have tried googling and searching on the Tex StackExchange, but I can't find any solution.

Edit: I need like 1 cm on each side of the page.

Edit: I need this(only 1cm on each side) [image]

Comment: Welcome! You can use e.g. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
 \draw[red,ultra thick] 
 ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=-1cm]current page text area.south west) 
 rectangle ([xshift=1cm,yshift=1cm]current page text area.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`.

Comment: Or, if you need it on all pages, `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
 \draw[red,ultra thick] 
 ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=-1cm]current page text area.south west) 
 rectangle ([xshift=1cm,yshift=1cm]current page text area.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-23]
\end{document}`.

Comment: It looks good, but  I need the border colored from the side of the page to 1 cm from it. Not only thin line. See my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now it is too long for a comment. You can use `tikzpagenodes` and `eso-pic`. If you want this only a specific page, use `\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{...}` with `...` as in the code below on that page. For all pages use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
 \fill[red,even odd rule] (current page.south west)
 rectangle (current page.north east)
 ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=-1cm]current page text area.south west) 
 rectangle ([xshift=1cm,yshift=1cm]current page text area.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-23]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That I exactly, what I want, Thank you.